# searching vector and summing based on value

Tags: matlab

I have 3 vectors.

First cell is called 'codes' is 25 x 1 vector, where each value is unique.
Second vector is called 'country' is n x 1 vector of doubles.
Third vector is called 'sales' is n x 1 vector of doubles.
n is approx. 3,500. Second and third vector will always contain the same number of rows.

What I would like to do is get the total sales for each code in my first vector. Please see example below.

```
 codes        
 3659
 7852
 3662
 1448


 country        sales
 3659           10
 1448           96
 3659           15
 3662           12
 3662           2
```

result I want,

```
 country        sales
 3659           25
 1448           96
 3662           14
 7852           0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i = 1:length(codes)
    newcountry(i) = codes(i);
    newsales(i) = sum(sales(country==codes(i)));
end
```

`country==codes(i)` gives a vector filled with zeros except at the indices where country = codes(i), in which case there is a 1.  `sales(country==codes(i))` returns the entries of sales at which `country` is the same as `codes(i)`. `sum(sales(country==codes(i)))` returns the sum of all sales at indices where `country` is the same as `codes(i)`.

Comment: I think you're missing a `sum()` in there somewhere

Comment: yeah, oops. misread the question.  thanks for pointing that out.  i have changed the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with the [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) function, which is precisely for this kind of job:

```
[~, ii] = ismember(country,codes);
totalSales = accumarray(ii, sales, [], @sum, 0);
result = [ codes totalSales ];
```

Note this gives the result sorted as the original codes, unlike in your example.